# Changing the Gödel-tag

Tags: discussion, tags

[image]

> Although the name is sometimes written without the umlaut as Godel , proper German orthography is to write it Goedel if the dots are omitted.

<sup>[*Wikipedia*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kurt_Goedel#cite_note-2)</sup>

**Assuming that [tag:gödel] doesn't work, could we at least replace [godel](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/godel) by [goedel](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/goedel)?**

*Please vote up if you agree.*

Comment: [tag:G%C3%B6del] doesn't work :(

Comment: @stoicfury Other character's can be turned on in tags on a per site basis, if you demonstrate a use for them. Speak to com-team.

Comment: I think umlauts and grave accents would both be needed to capture French and German thinkers' names "properly" -- might there be any others symbols we would want to argue for?

Comment: Well there's always MathJax, haha...but I think we've gotten turned down on that one enough times.

Comment: LaTeX in tags would be awesome. @JosephWeissman what about Žižek? :)

Comment: So I guess I will try to bug Community team about this to see what our options might be

Comment: I haven't been able to pin anyone down about this. It shouldn't be technically difficult, I think we just need to outline the parameters a bit. A good answer outlining how far we want this change to go (how many new symbols to include) would help this I think. --For now, I'm planning to have [tag:godel] replaced by [tag:goedel], given the overwhelming consensus here.

Comment: @JosephWeissman That consensus seems _also_ to establish itself at Physics Meta SE. http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/a/4332/17609

Answer (score 1):

Non-ASCII characters in tags must currently be enabled per-site, and are reserved for sites where the primary language isn't English. LaTeX in tags is *right out*.

I've added [goedel](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/goedel) as a synonym.

Comment: Shouldn't it be the other way around, with [tag:goedel] being the master and [tag:godel] being the synonym?

Comment: Considering the former wasn't being used, I don't really think so. Joseph can reverse them though if necessary.

Comment: @JosephWeissman Could you please do so?

Comment: @Gugg I tried to perform the merge and got a 'something bad happened' kind of error; I will plan to try again tomorrow...

Comment: @Joseph: you should be able to just go to [the list of tag synonyms](http://philosophy.stackexchange.com/tags/synonyms) and click "swap" (and *then* merge).

Comment: @JosephWeissman Thanks, it seems done!